# Python regex with multiple matches in the same string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

```py
test = '<tag>part1</tag><tag can have random stuff here>part2</tag>'
print(re.findall("<tag.*>(.*)</tag>", test))
```

It outputs:

```py
['part2']
```

The text can have any amount of "parts". I want to return all of them, not only the last one. What's the best way to do it?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to parse HTML with regular expressions... https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3001761

Comment: One way I thought of doing this is making a copy of the string, then erasing all matches of </tag> and then of <tag.*>, but I believe there's a better way to do this

Comment: The reason you're catching just one of the parts, is because you're using `*`, which is greedy. If you instead change the first `.*` to `.*?`, then the `?` modifier will make it non-greedy, which could do what you're trying to accomplish.

But as @jonrsharpe is pointing out, please don't use RegEx as a parsing-method for HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your `.*` to be `.*?` so that they are non-greedy. That will make your original example work:

```
import re

test = '<tag>part1</tag><tag can have random stuff here>part2</tag>'
print(re.findall(r'<tag.*?>(.*?)</tag>', test))
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> ['part1', 'part2']
> ```

Though it would probably be best to not try to parse this with just regex, but instead use a proper HTML parser library.